# Match all keywords using like in group MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table of keywords (ID,ean,keyword) and another table with product details. I want the search to return EANs where all keywords match at least once, however the closest I have got is the following, but this returns matches that have the first term in them 3 times for example.

To give an example, let's say I have a product called 'Generic headphones - iPhone, iPad, iPod' and I searched 'gen%' 'hea%' 'ip%' it would come back as a match, but it would also match 'Apple headphones - iPhone, iPad, iPod' due to the 3 ip words, which is not desired.

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/270f9/1/0)**
I want EAN 1 to match only, so matches need to be at least 1 for each term.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
SELECT     Count(keywords.ean) AS cc, 
           products.* 
FROM       keywords 
INNER JOIN products 
ON         products.ean = keywords.ean 
WHERE      ( 
                      keyword LIKE 'gen%' 
                                 || keyword like 'ip%' 
                                 || keyword LIKE 'hea%') 
GROUP BY   (keywords.ean) 
HAVING     cc>=3 
ORDER BY   `products`.`ean` ASC
```

UPDATE: This gets the desired results, but there must be more efficient ways to do this.

```
SELECT products.*
FROM products
INNER JOIN (SELECT ean, count(*) as tc1
                    FROM keywords
                    WHERE ( keyword like 'gen%' )
                    GROUP BY ean
                    HAVING tc1 > 0 ) as t1 ON t1.ean = products.ean
INNER JOIN (SELECT ean, count(*) as tc2
                    FROM keywords
                    WHERE ( keyword like 'ip%' )
                    GROUP BY ean
                    HAVING tc2 > 0 ) as t2 ON t2.ean = products.ean
INNER JOIN (SELECT ean, count(*) as tc3
                    FROM keywords
                    WHERE ( keyword like 'hea%' )
                    GROUP BY ean
                    HAVING tc3 > 0  ) as t3 ON t3.ean = products.ean
ORDER BY products.ean
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: OK, I've updated the post with an SQL Fiddle.

Comment: I think GregHNZ has nearly got it. Just change the `COUNT(*)` bit to `COUNT(DISTINCT keyword) = 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're after something more like this...

```
SELECT p.ean
     , p.description
  FROM products p 
  JOIN keywords k 
    ON k.ean = p.ean
 WHERE k.keyword LIKE 'iP%'  
    OR k.keyword LIKE 'hea%' 
    OR k.keyword LIKE 'gen%' 
 GROUP
    BY p.ean
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN k.keyword LIKE 'iP%' THEN 'iP' 
                           WHEN k.keyword LIKE 'hea%' THEN 'hea'
                           WHEN k.keyword LIKE 'gen%' THEN 'gen'
                           ELSE keyword END) = 3;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/270f9/25

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it in PostgreSQL.  MySQL may have a slightly different syntax.

```
SELECT kc.cc AS cc,
       products.*
FROM products
INNER JOIN (  SELECT ean, count(*) AS cc 
                    FROM keywords
                    WHERE ( keyword like 'ip%' 
                           OR keyword like 'ai%'
                           OR keyword like 'bei%' )
                    GROUP BY ean
                    HAVING count(*) >= 3 ) AS kc
       ON kc.ean = products.ean
ORDER BY Products.ean;
```